# Is it possible for my HTC Desire to interupt my iPod when I receive a call?

Tags: notifications, htc-desire, bluetooth, calls, headphones

I frequently miss incoming telephone calls because I am listening to my iPod Touch and I don't feel it vibrate.

Does anyone know if it's possible for my HTC Desire to somehow notify me of the call via my headphones?

I've seen bluetooth connection devices that purport to do this (such as the [GEAR4 BluEye](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/redirect.html?ie=UTF8&location=https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/yourstore?ie=UTF8&ref_=pd_irl_gw&signIn=1&tag=helenpieli-21&linkCode=ur2&camp=1634&creative=19450)), but they are several years old now.

However given that this kind of hardware exists, and that the Desire and the iPod Touch have Bluetooth built-in, I wondered if there was an app or setting that would enable the phone and iPod to work together in this way?

Comment: This is... interesting.  So what you want is an app that will push some kind of audio notification to your iPod Touch via Bluetooth that will play through the connected headphones when you receive a call?

Comment: @JonnyP - yes, exactly.

Comment: Well connecting the two devices via Bluetooth shouldn't be too much of a hassle, in theory.  And there are plenty of apps like Tasker which allow you to take any specified action upon any specified condition.  The trick here is going to be finding something that will essentially treat your iPod Touch as a BT headset or something similar.  I'll look around a bit and see what I can find.

Answer (score 1):

I've found something for you, although it may not treat your iPod the right way.  The only way to find out is for you to give it a shot.  Luckily the developer of this app offers a version that's a five day free trial.

Super BT Mono

If you're running stock Android 2.2 [try this](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.steven.supermonofroyofree).
If you're running CyanogenMod [try this](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.steven.supermono).

I'd follow the dev's instructions on how to get this up and running, and just treat your iPod like the BT headset with which this app is meant to interface.  It doesn't say so on the app page in the Market, but on some forum thread (of which I've unfortunately lost track, dammit) someone mentioned that it will send notification tones and ringtones to the BT device.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just listen to music on the Android device?

I have a sneaking suspicion that, given how Apple tends to be very restrictive about what gets into the App store, and even more restrictive about what apps can do, this probably wouldn't work simply.

On the Android side of things, it's a breeze to write an App (or maybe there's something out there already that can do it?) that would connect to the iPod over bluetooth and send some notification to pause, when a call comes in. The problem as I see it is that, unlike on Android, there's no real way (without jailbreaking the iPod) to just write an app for the iPod that listens over bluetooth and pauses when it gets the notification...